# Как сделать анимацию перед загрузкой фрейма?

Tags: javascript, iframe

У меня есть сайт, состоящий из двух фреймов: Меню и Контент.
В Меню есть каталог внешних ссылок, и при клике они открываются во фрейме, но так как это внешние сайты, загрузка происходит долго, и пользователь видит белый экран и порой не дожидается загрузки.

Я хочу, чтобы при клике по ссылке в главном окне происходила какая-то активность, это может быть заставка с загрузкой, слово "Подождите" или еще что-либо, но только не белый экран на протяжении 5 секунд, я порой сам думаю, что зависло, и тыкаю по ссылке два раза и жду, соотвественно, заново.

Я так понимаю, нужен какой-то скрипт, но какой? 
Я гуглил слова: prefetch, preload, prerender, но так как я мало разбираюсь в скриптах, я так и не понял, что делать.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nikesh.me/blog/2010/05/ajax-style-loading-animation-in-css3-no-images/

http://codepen.io/alextebbs/pen/tHhrz

Comment: @Гошка Тарасов, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение.